# Unable to read .txt file using Command Line in c++

Tags: c++, command-line

I am trying to read a .txt file which looks like "-f Filename.txt". The project I am working on requires me to look for the name of the file after the "-f", open the file with that name and extract the information into a vector string.

I was able to do all that except the extraction. For some reason it won't open the file.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    vector <string> lines;
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp( argv[1], "-f" )==0)
        {
            cout << "I am here" << endl;
            std::string argv2 = argv[2];
            cout << argv2 << endl;

            file.open(argv2.c_str());

            if(!file.is_open())
            {
               cout << "file failed to open" << endl;
            }
            while (getline(file, line)) 
            {
                lines.push_back(line);
            }
         }
    }

    for (unsigned int j=0; j<lines.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << lines[j] << endl;
    }
```

my output is

```
I am here
test.txt
file failed to open
```

x3

I really don't get it because the `file.open(argv2.c_str());` worked when I put a `string filename` instead of `argv2` but they are both strings... right?

The -f test.txt file is under my project folder and the test.txt is under Debug folder. I also added -f test.txt in program arguments.

Comment: Are you sure that the file actually exists in the current directory?

Comment: Yea I put it there...

Comment: Just to be sure: use the full path to your file, for example -f c:\temp\filename.txt

Comment: Works on my machine™.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run from an IDE like Visual Studio then the default current directory when running is *not* where the executable file is, but the project root directory.

Either change the arguments to `-f Debug\test.txt`, or move the file to the project root directory.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should rename the file to `test.txt`, not `-f test.txt`.

It seems as thought the `-f` part is supposed to be interpreted as a command, not part of the file name.

Comment: -f is part of the command being run, essentially one of its arguments.

Comment: Oh God ok so I don't need the -f.. I was told it will work if I write it with the -f. Very confusing... but your way works. Thanks

Comment: No problem, you can tell by the fact that your program outputs the `argv2` variable as `"test.txt"`, so that is the file it's going to try and open :)